# How to get data from 2 collections and bind them together in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem with the understanding of the loading with sub-collections. I have two collection one is the posts collection and the comments collection. In the posts collection, there are posts inside with a unique `postId` and each post has different comments in the comments collection. (See below)

My goal is to get for each post the associated one's comments.

```
users -> 'userId' -> posts -> 'postId' -> comments -> 'commentId'
```

my code

```
// get posts
firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(userId).collection('posts')
 .get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        this.posts.push(doc.data());
    });
});
```

```
// get comments
firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(userId).collection('posts').doc(postId).collection('comments')
 .get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        this.comments.push(doc.data());
    });
});
```

`vue.js` code

```
...
<v-timeline-item
  v-for="(item, index) in comments"
  :key="index"
>
  <span>{{item.content}}</span>
</v-timeline-item>
```

I know how to add the comments from one post to the post. But what is if I would like to show more posts and for each post all comments?

Comment: Hi, are you still looking for a solution?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do? Is it getting all the comments belonging to every post? If so, you will need to iterate through them all. That is, you would do the second code snippet for every `postId` you obtained from the first snippet. You could wrap the second snippet in another `forEach` statement, iterating over the array of posts that results from the first snippet.

Comment: I have found a solution by using `collectionGroup`

Comment: Great! If that solutions worked out for you, would you mind sharing it here?This will help other users who may run into the same situation and give closure to this post.